# Facebook thumbnail

Tags: c#, facebook, html

Facebook doesn't show thumbnail from my web page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="httpdocs_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta property="og:image" runat="server" content="http://fuzzel.org/Images/mercedes.jpg"/>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Welcome to Fuzzel
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and I also get Message 1 Validation (HTML5): Attribute 'property' is not a valid attribute of element 'meta' message.
I also used developers.facebook.com/tools/debug and it shows thumbnail there, but when i post www.fuzzel.org as a status, it doesn't show thumbnail

Comment: Could you clarify your problem? What is the expected outcome? How does this code relate to Facebook?

Comment: This is just a simple example of a web page that has facebook thumbnail. I found solution. The image needs to be 200x200 pixels to work. I don't know why is that